# What are the changes I have to made in php.ini to move the uploaded files to a remote server?

Tags: php

My php application is running in a master-slave server with load balance. Some times the upload request will redirect to the slave server and the files will uploaded to the slave only. It will not sync with the master. I want to change the file upload path of the apache server of slave to master. What should I do in php.ini to achieve this without making modification in my application?

Comment: look into NFS. PHP can't handle "remote" uploads. Or setup rsync on each server to copy the file on both. Best solution in my opinion is to have a dedicated server for storage and after the file upload (regardless of server - master, slave) move the file to the storage server and delete the original.

Answer (score 0):

php.ini can't deal with that (as far as I know). The only options I can think of are:

a) The only solution I've used is to have a separately mounted file system to upload file to - so either system can upload the files to essentially the same place. (Make sure the file_system in in the base dir restrictions is you have them enabled - so oyu many need ot mod php.ini for that.)

b) The load balancer needs to redirect calls of one type to always the same server (i.e. the master). I'm no expert on load balancing so don't know if this is possible.

(And c, that your question rules out, is to split the application into two.)